# Access Requests settings explanation

Tags: sharepoint-online, access

I have recently problems with Access Request Settings. The thing is that I do not understand the difference between first two options. I have tested it with two users: user A is a member of the web and user B has no access to the web. User A is trying to share the site and the site content with the user B.

If I leave both first options checked user A can share everything without problems with user B. The site owner is not informed or asked for confirmation by email. If user A share the site user B is automatically added to the Members group. I get this option.

If I leave the first option unchecked, but the second is checked, user A can share site and contents with user B, but only after the site owner approved the request which is sent to him via email.

If I leave the first option checked and the second unchecked, the behavior is just the same - the site owner has to approved the sharing (both sites and content).

If I leave both options unchecked the behavior is also the same.

What is the difference between these options? Please help!

Many thanks!

[image]